# Elasticsearch: Must include all words in search if all exist, but ignore one or two if they don't?

Tags: elasticsearch

I hope what I'm trying to explain makes sense, and there is a way that I could achieve it.

Currently I am searching in 40 million documents, with a query like this:

```
GET /all/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "full_text": {
        "query": "insert ten or twelve words here to search",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to only return docs that their 'full_text' includes all of the words in the query. I am able to achieve that with above snippet.

My question is, when there is no match at all, but for example removing "ten" would yield one result, is there a way to configure my search to do that? I.e. to tell ES "aim for 100% match, but if nothing found, 90% would do just fine" !

Hope this is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [minimum_should_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) clause along with match query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text":{
        "query": "insert ten or twelve words here",
        "minimum_should_match":"90%"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So there is no way I could use "minimum_should_match" and "operator": "and" at the same time? Do you think I would have to make my query, and if it came back empty, do one with minimum_should_match?

Comment: operator "and" will mean all the words should exist. In that case there will be no use of minimum_should_match.. "And " acts as 100% match.  text with more matched words will score higher so you can pick top most from result if you want only one result.